# calculate every time the corresponding value of row "A" changes

Tags: excel, formula

I need a formula that will calculate: ((Average of ZL * 11)+(Average of ZM * 2.2)) - (Average of ZS * 100) The problem with creating a simple formula is that I need This calculation every time the price of ZS changes. Not only when the price of ZS changes but when the quantity of ZS orders add up and be a multiple of 10. In the example given, it would be calculated at Order ID 6, 12, and 18. it is very difficult to explain sorry if it comes across confusing. Trying to sum it up, every time ZS changes price AND adds up to a multiple of 10, i need the average of each of the three contracts to be put into that calculation.

```
OrderID  Contract  Price  BuySell OrderType Quantity
   1        ZS     10914  Buy                   6
   2        ZS     10916  Buy                   4
   3        ZL      3188  Sell                  9
   4        ZM      3981  Sell                  9
   5        ZM      3985  Sell                  2
   6        ZS     10914  Buy                  10
   7        ZL      3186  Sell                  9
   8        ZM      3982  Sell                 11
   9        ZS     10910  Buy                   2
   10       ZS     10911  Buy                   4
   11       ZS     10913  Buy                   2
   12       ZS     10914  Buy                   4
   13       ZL      3184  Sell                  9
   14       ZM      3983  Sell                 11
   15       ZS     10926  Buy                  10
   16       ZL      3184  Sell                  9
   17       ZM      3983  Sell                 11
   18       ZS     10926  Buy                  10
   19       ZL      3184  Sell                  9
   20       ZM      3983  Sell                 11
```

Comment: I have fixed your post so that the data table is readable.  I still have no idea what you're asking for.  What are your expected results?

Comment: Your explanation would make more sense to me if the IDs to change would be Order ID 6, 15, and 18 (in the above example) and not Order ID 6, 12, and 18. But like this I have also difficulties understanding.

Comment: You should update your table to show what the output should look like.

Comment: @Ralph 6, 12, and 18 should be calculated, because at each of those points, the sum of the quantity of ZS contracts are intervals of 10 and at each of those orderID the price changes

Comment: The quantity for ID 12 is 4. This is clearly **NOT** a multiple of 10!

Comment: Please bear with me as it is hard to explain without being able to point things out. Think of the quantity column as a running total. For ZS specifically, If you add up every quantity that corresponds with ZS since the last "10" quantity, ID 12 will be the next multiple of 10.